# Expecting an identifier

Tags: verilog

The code was working fine earlier. I just switched A and B from being represented by switches to just being modular inputs.

The error message:

`Error (10170): Verilog HDL syntax error at Part4.v(6) near text "4";  expecting an identifier`

The following code produces the error:

```
module 4bitAdder(A,B,Cin,LEDG);
    input [0:3] A;
    input [0:3] B;
    input [0:1] Cin;
    output [0:4] LEDG;

    fulladder FA1(Cin,A[0],B[0],c1,s0);
    fulladder FA2(c1,A[1],B[1],c2,s1);
    fulladder FA3(c2,A[2],B[2],c3,s2);
    fulladder FA4(c3,A[3],B[3],c4,s3);

    assign LEDG[4] = c4;
    assign LEDG[3] = s3;
    assign LEDG[2] = s2;
    assign LEDG[1] = s1;
    assign LEDG[0] = s0;

endmodule

module fulladder(carryin,a,b,carryout,s);
    input carryin, a, b;
    output carryout, s;
    assign s = a ^ b ^ carryin;
    assign carryout = (a & b)|(a & carryin)|(b & carryin);

endmodule
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe all verilog names must start with a letter, thus making your '4bitAdder' name illegal.

Try a different module name starting with a letter.

Comment: An underscore and, in the case of an escaped identifier, a backslash are valid as well.